# I'm having trouble optimizing my code on large numbers

Tags: python

The first line of input contains three integers separated by single ones

> intervals : , , , where 1 < ≤ 1000000 / 0 < ≤ 10000 and 1 < ≤ 10000
> N - the greatest power
> x - a certain amount of input
> n - is used to limit the sum of the output for using modulo operation.
> and next line is followed by  - 1 lines, each containing a single non-negative integer
> no more than 10000
> For example for the input data:
> 5 2 100
> 2
> 8
> 1
> 3
> the correct result is:
> 84
> because

```
2 * (2**2) = 8
8 * (2**3) = 64
1 * (2**4) = 16
3 * (2**5) = 96
8 + 64 + 16 + 96 = 184
184 % 100 = 84
```

And this is my python code that I need to optimize for larger variables:

```
N, x, n = map(int, input().split())
sum = 0
for power in range(2,N+1):
   sum+= (int(input())* (x**power))
   sum = sum%n 
print(sum)
```

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the modulo n to the power and to the result as you go. Also, you can accumulate the power by multiplying by x at each iteration rather than working with huge numbers (which eventually gets slower)

```
N, x, n = map(int, input().split())
result = 0
power  = x*x                         # x^2, x^3 ...
for _ in range(N-1):                 # read N-1 values 
    result += int(input())*power     # add product of power
    result %= n                      # reduce as you go with modulo
    power = power*x % n              # accumulate power (modulo n)
    
print(result) # 84
```